# Common values in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

Array 1:

```
$strong_areas=array(
                '192'=>57,
                '187'=>43,
                '121'=>85,
                '198'=>74
              );
```

Array 2:

```
$weak_areas=array(
                '109'=>57,
                '187'=>54,
                '181'=>85,
                '198'=>25
            );
```

I need resultant array like this:

```
array(
        '192'=>57, //57-0
        '187'=>-11, //43-54
        '121'=>85, //85-0
        '198'=>49, //74-25
        '109'=>-57, // 0-57
        '181'=>-85, //0-85
    )
```

What I tried so far:

```
//for common keys in both arrays
$temp=array_intersect_key($strong_areas,$weak_areas);

//for unique ones from first to second
$strong_final_array=array_diff_key($strong_areas, $weak_areas); 

//for unique ones from second to first 
$weak_final_array=array_diff_key($weak_areas, $strong_areas); 

foreach ($weak_final_array as &$value){
   $value *= (-1);
}

//returning final values for common keys in array  
$common=array();
foreach($temp as $key => $value){
    $common[$key]=$strong_areas[$key]-$weak_areas[$key];
} 

//getting final results
$final_array=array_merge($strong_final_array,$weak_final_array,$common);
```

The question is, is the above procedure best practice or is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify the calculations and how to get to the "resultant array". I don't understand calculations for e.g. key 187, 121 ....

Comment: i don`t understand the logic.

Comment: you should directly insert values to resultant array since there were no rhymes and reason how do you want this ...can u plz clarify what do you want exactly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

```
$final_result = array();
foreach (array_keys($strong_areas + $weak_areas) as $join_key) {
  $final_result[$join_key] = ( isset($strong_areas[$join_key]) ? $strong_areas[$join_key] : 0 ) - ( isset($weak_areas[$join_key]) ? $weak_areas[$join_key] : 0 );
}
print_r($final_result);
```

The output array is

```
Array
(
[192] => 57
[187] => -11
[121] => 85
[198] => 49
[109] => -57
[181] => -85
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use native php function: array_merge_recursive and array_walk. The benefit is they're php core function (which is written in C) and execute faster than using php foreach.

```
// this will return array with keys combined from argument arrays,
// value will be scalar if key only exist in 1 argument,
// and value will be array if key exist in multiple arguments
$result_array = array_merge_recursive($strong_areas,$weak_areas);

// this step will walk through result array and change its array value
// into subtraction of elements 
array_walk($result_array, function ($element) {
    if (is_array($element)) {
        return $element[0] - $element[1];
    } else {
        return $element;
    }
});
```

It's just sample code. You can make it more fancy by yourself
Regards,